# Extension of $\int_K f(x)f'(x)dx$ to high dimension

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We know from simple Calculus that,
$$\int_K f(x)f'(x)dx=\frac{f^2(x)}{2}|_K$$
Suppose we have a function $u$ defined on $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d=2,3$. Then, can we say
$$\int_\Omega u\nabla u.\mathbb{n}dS=\frac{u^2}{2}|_{\Omega}$$
where $\mathbb{n}$ is the outward unit normal and $\Omega$ is a simple domain such as a square or triangle.

Comment: The second formula does not make sense if $\Omega$ is an open domain: what is the normal vector in the interior of $\Omega$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Even in 1D, the divergence theorem tells you that the integral of $\nabla \cdot u$ over a domain $\Omega$ is the surface integral of $\nabla u \cdot n$ on the boundary of $\Omega$. In 1D there are just simplifications: $\nabla \cdot u$ and $\nabla u$ are both $u'$, all domains are intervals, the normal is just $+1$ on the right and $-1$ on the left, and the surface measure is just the sum of Dirac measures at the endpoints. As a result, in higher dimensions it's not as simple as "plug in the endpoints and subtract"; you still have an integral to evaluate on the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the second expression should be written as:

$$\int_{\partial V}u \nabla u\ d\vec{\omega}$$

Assuming that the integrand is differentiable enough, we can use the following relation (which you can verify by yourself):

$$\nabla (a\nabla b)=a \Delta b+\nabla a \cdot \nabla b$$

as well as Gauss´ law ([Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)) to show that:

$$\int_{\partial V}u \nabla u\ d\vec{\omega}=\int_{V} u \Delta u+(\nabla u)^{2}\ dV$$